# Post Events to Facebook (out of Wordpress / PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I have really searched for a long time to get this working or to find a plugin which does exactly that. Maybe I am understanding something wromg:

I want to automatically create an event (not a normal post) on Facebook with some Content from a facebook post (normal post or post type event from Events Manager Plugin). Is there a simple solution without doing the whole authentication process and API-Tings on my own?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create events via the Graph API. So it's not what you want to achieve.